# What's a Phony Word?

Tags: word-property

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a **Phony Word**. Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Phony Words | Not Phony Words |
| --- | --- |
| FISH | FROG |
| BAGHDAD | BOGOTA |
| PACKED | STUFFED |
| MOONING | SUNNING |
| FUSS | BOTHER |
| TICKET | COUPON |
| MINIMA | LOWS |
| WORRY | FRET |
| TUT | BOP |
| ABU DHABI | KHOR FAKKAN |

A hint, added later:

> The vast majority of English words are not Phony.

<sub>This continues the [What is a Word/Phrase](/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aq) series started by [JLee](/u/463).</sub>

Comment: Do "Phony Words" also exist in other languages?

Answer (score 4):

Suspected answer:

> The consonants of each Phony Word all appear to belong to *only one* of these groups:
>  p/t/k
>  b/d/g
>  f/s/sh
>  v/z/ж
>  m/n/ng
>  r/w

Example:

> FISH contains "f" and "sh" which are all in the f/s/sh group.
>  FROG contains "f", "r", and "g", which do not belong to the same group (**f**/s/sh, **r**/w, b/d/**g**).

Comment: More specifically, rot13(gurfr tebhcf bs pbafbanagf ner onfrq ba znaare bs negvphyngvba. Sbe rknzcyr, z/a/at ner nyy anfny pbafbanagf naq e/j ner nccebkvznagf.) And of course, the title is relevant because this puzzle is about rot13(CUBARZRF)!

Comment: Retracting downvote now that I realise how it makes sense. Thanks for spelling it out, @noneuclideanisms :)

Comment: @non pretty much has it. But note that _bop_ is non-phony.

Comment: @msh210 "b" and "p" are in different groups.

Comment: I was replying to @non

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it means, but according to Wikipedia it has to do with the rot13(qvssrerapr orgjrra sbegvf naq yravf cebahapvngvbaf?)